# Script Task Corrupt - SSISDB execution error after upgrading from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2016 SP2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We recently updated our production SQL Server 2016 Enterprise instance from SP1 to SP2. We are currently on version 13.0.5026. Prior to the upgrade, a user with connect rights to SSISDB and proper rights on the Integration Services Catalog folder could deploy an ISPAC file successfully.

After the upgrade, the same users can still deploy to the SSISDB, but when you execute the `.DTSX`, the script task inside fails validation. If I deploy the exact same ISPAC as a sysadmin, there's no issue. The usual solution I've seen is to confirm that SSDT Configuration Properties are set to SQL Server 2016. We have verified this is set correctly prior to building the ISPAC.

I saw a similar issue when migrating from SQL Server 2014 to 2016 a couple years back, but the solution at that time was to give the Proxy account that runs the package modify rights to the `C:\Windows\Temp` folder so it can generate temp files. This new issue is hard to pin down, and I don't want to give out sysadmin just so others can do the simple deployment steps.

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

*******Update/edit************:

The server has a SQL Server 2016 deployment tool located under SQL Server/130/DTS/Binn - ISDeploymentWizard.exe. This deployment tool works. There is another identical wizard under the 140/DTS/Binn location, same name but 1 KB larger (assuming this is because SSMS is a separate install now, and I installed latest and greatest on server). This one fails deployment. I'm banging my head against the wall as to why one works but the other doesn't. Locally we all use SSMS 2017, and with that we get the 140/DTS/Binn ISDeployment file, not the 130 (since that's SQL Server 2016 and we're using SSMS 2017, which I thought was backwards compatible). Either way, this problem just started occurring and we've been on the same version of SSMS for a few months.

[Image of the Execution information report from SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSfFE.png)

[image]

Comment: You can always diff the converted `.dtsx` files to see if there's any smoking gun. Comparing these is no fun, but I've had no end of grief with script tasks converting from an admittedly much older version to 2017, which the wizards simply neglected to do -- I ended up having to manually edit the package to make the script task project definitions match a "vanilla" script task as created in a brand new package. If your package is still using an old version and you're relying on on the fly upgrades to save the day, they might not be doing that.

Comment: Hi raveseer, I got the same error but in my case in need to deploy the project in SQL Server 2014.  Can I use the wizard under the 130/DTS/Binn location or i have to use other ?

Comment: Hi Sql Programmer, the wizard under 130 folder is meant for SQL Server 2016. If you try using it you MAY run into the same issues that I had with using the 140 version, since you're using a deployment utility that is a version newer than your SQL server. I'd advise you find the proper 120 compatibility version to do deployments. Again, I'm not sure on if it will work for you or not, you'll need to test. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had resolved a similar issue with C# scripts recently. In short: don't use 140 version of ISDeploymentWizard.exe with MS SQL 2016. It apparently mangles something in C# code, or components' properties, and 2016 runtime stops recognising them.

In my case, a package with C# script source has started to throw the following error during the validation phase:

> Error: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ComponentVersionMismatchException:
>
> The version of `C# source component name` is not compatible with this
>   version of the DataFlow. [[The version or pipeline version or both for
>   the specified component is higher than the current version.  This
>   package was probably created on a new version of DTS or the component
>   than is installed on the current PC.]]
>       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostCheckAndPerformUpgrade(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100
>   wrapper, Int32 lPipelineVersion)

The first comment [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32898370-deploying-single-ssis-package-to-sql-2016-from-ssd) has helped me to ultimately identify the cause.

Comment: Thank you Roger. I was just coming to update my post because i found this same thing out yesterday. Apparently just because they made Data Tools backwards compatible with previous versions, they didn't do the same with the ISDeploymentWizard. We were able to successfully use the 130/DTS/Binn version, and we're installing SSDT 2016 side by side on developer machines to get them the 130 version of the utility.