# Version mismatch between SSIS and Sql Integration Services

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have multiple SSIS packages originally written on Visual Studio 2015, targeting Sql Server 2016.  As part of an upgrade effort, we are recompiling those packages in VS 2017, still targeting Sql 2016.  When deploying the packages to the Integration Server, Sql Server version 13, I get the following error:

There was an exception while loading Script Task from XML: System.Exception: The Script Task "ST_8c5c4e0d540b46d6a710de422f267e7d" uses version 14.0 script that is not supported in this release of Integration Services. ...etc.

Even though we have selected Sql Server 2016 as the target in SSDT I am finding that the script task has a reference to version 14

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\SSIS\140\Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll

However, packages produced by a different team approximately a year earlier but also in VS2017 are running fine on the same integration server.  When I open them up I find that the script task references version 13 as it should.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Tasks\Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll

I have tried changing the ScriptTask reference in my package to match the older packages but to no avail.  Same error when deployed to the integration server.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you had the wrong target selected when you created the Script Task, and therefore the script task is designed for a later version of SQL Server. Each one uses a different .Net Framework, and if you are using functionality that is available in one, and not the other, you'll have this problem. Found this out the hard way a couple of years ago when built a project, then changed the deployment target to 2012 and found out that several functions I were using simply weren't available in the older Framework. Lesson learned was already create projects in the lowest target version needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Script Task Corrupt - SSISDB execution error after upgrading from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2016 SP2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53507614/script-task-corrupt-ssisdb-execution-error-after-upgrading-from-sql-server-201)

Comment: In addition to VS2017 did you install the [SQL Server Data Tools for VS2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt#ssdt-for-vs-2017-standalone-installer)? This is different than the Data Storage and Processing workload that's available in the VS2017 installer. They say on that page, "to create Analysis Services, Integration Services, or Reporting Services projects, you still need the SSDT standalone installer."